# Three.js - ColladaLoader - Animated model (DAE) - Black texture

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I loaded a DAE file based on the ColladaLoader example. I exported from Maya 2012, including a skin. I already had to fix 1 thing by adding the "skeleton" tag in the .dae file otherwise I'd get the error Couldn't find skin. Then I thought if thats a problem perhaps I need to change the localized url of the skin material to just name.jpg because they are in the same folder. But that didn't work.

So my question is: Am I doing something wrong? Or missing something? Already tried of few techniques of editing the material afterwards, they did work but then the model stopped animating.

You can see it live here: http://www.mariusposthumus.nl/playground/webgl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try exporting with OpenCollada instead:
https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenCOLLADA/wiki/OpenCOLLADA-Tools

Answer (score 0):

Black texture appear when you apply compressed file format texture like png, jpg, tga, or dds , use bmp (bitmap uncompressed) instead it will work.
I've had the same problem but i solved it in this way, seems that colladaloader don't read compressed file format.
It's an old issue that i've had also when i made my first application in OpenGL.
To read compressed file format you need to decode it, and this take a lot of time and a lot of more coding.... ;-)